# How to change the directory of an appication in the main menu

Tags: desktop

I am running a raspberry pi 4 model B, using LXPannel, and i am trying to organize my main menu. But i have not found a way to move an  application from one place(like education) to another(such as programing) i have tried going into both /usr/share/applications and ~/.local/menu and editing the .desktop files and i have tried going into menu:// to change the folders but every time i do that it just resets back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this for years (when I added a new application BitScope).
AFAIK you can't "move" items, but you can create a New Item.

Go to Menu `Preferences/Main Menu Editor`
You can create a `New Item` and edit its properties.

I vaguely remember I couldn't have items with the same name in different menus.